# How can I test oclif CLI that consumes Rest API

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, command-line-interface, oclif

How can I test the following code build using Typescript in Oclif? This CLI consumes a rest api build with node.js and express.js. I am testing my api with mocha/chai which I have become familiar with. However, I saw the example on the oclif site about testing, but besides that there is no actual help with testing. How can I test the following code which is a command from my cli?

```
import cli from 'cli-ux'
// just prompt for input
import {Command} from '@oclif/command'
import {createConnection} from "typeorm";
import {flags} from  '@oclif/command'
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var fs=require('fs');
const https = require('https')
const axios=require('axios');
const client_cert = fs.readFileSync('ca-crt.pem')
axios.defaults.httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ca : client_cert, keepAlive: true})
export class AdminCommand extends Command {
  static flags = { 
    newuser: flags.string({dependsOn:['passw'],exclusive:['newdata','userstatus','moduser']}),
    moduser: flags.string({dependsOn:['passw'],exclusive:['newuser','newdata','userstatus']}),
    passw: flags.string({dependsOn:['email']}),
    email: flags.string({dependsOn:['quota']}),
    quota: flags.string(),
    userstatus: flags.string({exclusive:['newdata','newuser','moduser']}),
    newdata: flags.string({dependsOn:['source'],exclusive:['userstatus','newuser','moduser']}),
    source: flags.string()
  }
  async run() {
    const {flags} = this.parse(AdminCommand); 
    var fs=require('fs');
    var jwt=require('jsonwebtoken');
    var token = fs.readFileSync('softeng19bAPI.token','utf-8');
    axios.defaults.headers.common['X-OBSERVATORY-AUTH']=token;
    await cli.anykey();
    //create new user
    if (`${flags.newuser}` !== "undefined" && `${flags.passw}` !== "undefined" && `${flags.email}` !== "undefined" && `${flags.quota}` !== "undefined" ){
            let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(`${flags.passw}`,10);
            let body = new Object ({
                username: `${flags.newuser}`,
                passw: `${flags.passw}`,
                email: `${flags.email}`,
                quota: `${flags.quota}` 
            })
            await axios.post('https://localhost:8765/energy/api/Admin/users',body);

    } }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Oclif Testing](https://oclif.io/docs/testing) section includes an example of mocking an HTTP request using nock. To test this I would:

1. Mock your post request using nock
2. Prompt a **success message** if the post request is successful and assert that
3. Prompt an **error message** if the post request fails and assert that too

A **CLI is a User Interface**, it made my life easier to think of it as such when testing. So design your tests to assert the CLI output and use unit tests for the business logic.

```
// Success test case, assuming the command name is 'admin:create'

  
describe('admin', () => {

  const newUser = {...}

  test
  .stdout()
  .nock('https://localhost:8765', api =>
    api
    .persist()
    .post('/energy/api/Admin/users')
    .reply(200, newUser)
  )
  .command('admin:create')
  .it('shows success message when user is created', ctx => {
    expect(ctx.stdout).to.contain('User was successfully created.')
  })
})
```